# Utilizar ConstraintLayout para administrar la posición de un fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

Tengo una pregunta, lo que deseo hacer es utilizar el ConstraintLayout que he definido con las propiedades que tiene para poder añadir y posicionar en tiempo de ejecución el fragment.

Preferiría ponerlo con código y no a través de xml.

De momento el código que tengo funciona, pero lo único que hace es poner el fragment a través del SupportFragmentManager pero no sé como modificar la posición de este fragment ya que tengo un ConstraintLayout que en teoría podría utilizar para mandar el fragment hacia la parte de abajo (de momento, por defecto se va a la parte de arriba).

Mi código en mi Activity es el siguiente (funciona, pero no de la manera que quiero).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //TODO use constraintLayout to manage fragment position (ask)
    ConstraintLayout activityLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_app_container);
    if (activityLayout != null){
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        TabFragment tabFragment = TabFragment.newInstance();
        tabFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.main_app_container, tabFragment)
                .commit();


    }
```

El código xml del ConstraintLayout es el siguiente (practicamente, es solo un container para fragments).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_app_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.xdxdxd.android.xdxdxdxd.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Una imagen es la siguiente:

[image: Imagen tabs - se van a top, pero quiero que ese fragment se vaya bot]

Comment: Puedes mostrar el código de tu `ConstraintLayout`?

Comment: @David ok, edité el post

Comment: El fragmento ocupa toda la pantalla o solo una parte. Aun necesito un poco mas de información para darte una respuesta acertada. El código del xml de tu fragmento y una imagen de como se ven en el dispositivo seria de mucha ayuda.

Comment: @David mande una imagen, pero el codigo xml del fragment solo le da formato, y le setea las propiedades width y height

Comment: Ok, cual es el valor que le das al width y al height del fragmento?

Comment: @David Width: `android:layout_width="match_parent"` Height: `android:layout_height="60dp"`

Comment: Aun me hace falta el codigo xml de tu fragmento para darte una solución.

Answer (score 1):

Primero necesitas la instancia de tu `ConstraintLayout`

```
ConstraintLayout con_layout = findViewById(R.id.main_app_container);
```

Después agrega el `fragment`.

Luego crea un objeto `ConstraintSet` y clona las restricciones del `ConstraintLayout`.

```
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(con_layout);
```

---

El objeto `ConstraintSet` es el que utiliza el `ConstraintLayout` para acomodar todos los `Views`.

Ahora, utiliza el `ConstraintSet` para posicionar tu `fragment`.
Lo puedes hacer a través de diferentes métodos que ofrece `ConstraintSet`.

En tu caso, lo que tienes que hacer es conectar el lado de abajo del `fragment` al lado de abajo del `ConstraintLayout` a través del método `connect()`.

ConstraintSet#connect() requiere 4 parámetros:

1. El `Id` del `View` que quieres conectar (En tu caso el `Id` del `fragment`).
2. El lado del `View` que quieres conectar (Arriba | Abajo | Izquierda | Derecha) en tu caso vas a conectar el lado de abajo del `fragment` (`ConstraintSet.BOTTOM`)
3. El `Id` del `View` al que vas a conectar el `View` (Osea el `id` del `View` al que vas a conectar tu `fragment`).
4. A que lado de ese `View` vas a conectar tu `fragment` (Vas a conectar el lado de abajo del view, al lado de abajo del `ConstraintLayout` - `ConstraintSet.BOTTOM`).

Quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
constraintSet.connect(id_del_fragment, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, id_del_constraint_layout o (ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
```

Finalmente, tienes que aplicar ese `ConstraintSet` al `ConstraintLayout` con el método: `constraintSet.applyTo(id_del_constraint_layout);`